# VB.NET SQL ACCESS Insert Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

net and i'm trying to insert data into access database using sql, i have the code below, when i try to execute, it prompts me an error message and highlighting con.open() i don't understand why it's not working, can anyone guide me. Thank

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddBut.Click

        Dim dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= c:\Databse\Company_db.accdb"
        Dim dbSource = "Data Source= C:\Databse\Company_db.accdb"

        Dim empNum As String
        Dim empFname As String
        Dim empLname As String
        Dim empDept As String
        Dim empStat As String
        Dim empYears As String


        empNum = eNumText.Text
        empFname = empFnameText.Text
        empLname = empLnameText.Text
        empDept = Deptd.Text
        empStat = Statd.Text
        empYears = yearstext.Text




        Dim sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_empinfo (EmpID, FirstName, LastName, Department, Status, Years " & _
           ") " & _
           "Values(empNum, empFname, empLname, empDept, empStat, empYears)"

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
            con.Open()
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EmpID", empNum)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FirstName", empFname)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LastName", empLname)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Department", empDept)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Status", empStat)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Years", empYears)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        End Using


        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Have you misspelled C:\Databse\? Perhaps C:\Database\

Comment: @Remou nope that's really is exactly my folder's name :(

Answer (score 3):

Standard problem, when you see a Syntax error in an otherwise fine SQL statement, look for RESERVED KEYWORDS for the underlying database.

In your case the word POSITION is a reserved keyword for MS-ACCESS.
Put it between square brackets

```
Dim sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_empinfo (EmpID, FirstName, LastName, Department, " & _ 
          "[Position], Status, Years) " & _ 
          "Values(empNum, empFname, empLname, empDept, empStat, empYears)"
```

However, you have another error in that query. You have 7 fields to insert but you pass only 6 parameters, missing just the parameter for the POSITION field.

You need to fix also the connection string. You write

```
  con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
```

but this result in an invalid file name

```
  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= 
   c:\Databse\Company_db.accdbData Source= C:\Databse\Company_db.accdb"
```

(line splitted for readability)

Comment: +1 for this. @OP please also see this link for reserved keywords. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx

Comment: i tried to follow your advise and have this http://pastebin.com/J1kFBFT9 but it's still giving me the exact error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Not a valid file name." message and highlighting con.Open() I still don't get it why?

Comment: Possible typo in the folder name? `C:\Databse`, still missing the 7th parameter

Comment: @Steve nope Sir, i have the exact Path as Databse, i have updated my Parameters from my code above sorry about that, but it's still giving me the same error :(

Comment: I see you define the connection string with `con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource`, but the variable dbProvider already contains the DataSource part, try fixing that leaving just one Data Source part

Comment: The one causing the whole syntax to fail is dbProvider, Kudos Sir Steve!

Answer (score 0):

I consider that you have initialized the object of "OleDbConnection".

Try to get the Connection String from the Property window of your database (From Server Explorer Window right click on your database select properties option).

And when you are opening the connection use following code:

```
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If
```

Hope it helps you.